# C++ template class specialization: why do common methods need to be re-implemented

Tags: c++, templates, specialization

In the sample:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class B
{
public:
    virtual void pvf() = 0;
};

template <class T>
class D : public B
{
public:
    D(){}

    virtual void pvf() {}

private:
    string data;
};

template <>
class D<bool> : public B
{
public:
    D();

    virtual void pvf(){ cout << "bool type" << endl; }
};

int main()
{
    D<int> d1;
    D<bool> d2;
}
```

I get the following error:

```
test.cpp:(.text+0x1c): undefined reference to `D<bool>::D()'
```

*Note that the reason I don't just specialize the D() by itself is I want to eliminate the need for string `D<T>::data` in the `D<bool>` case.*

Why do I need to re-implement `D()` in `D<bool>`? Seems like there should be a way for me to tell the compiler to use the version from `D<T>`.

Is there any way to do a simple specialization like this without having to re-implement methods?

Comment: Because it is a whole new type.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

No, there is not.

Specialization is behaving very differently than inheritence. It has no connection to the generic template version.

When you use/instantiate a template, the compiler will create a new type name, and then look for how this type is defined. When it finds a specialization, then it takes that as the definition for the new type. When it does not, it takes the generic template and instantiates it.

Therefore they have no connection, and you are just writing an entirely new class, just with a special name for the compiler to find in case of someone using/instantiating the template to find it under that name.

Answer (score 20):

Each specialisation of a class template gives a different class - they do not share any members with each other. Since you've explicitly specialised the entire class, you don't get any of the members from the template, and must implement them all.

You can explicitly specialise individual members, rather than the entire class:

```
template <> void D<bool>::pvf(){ cout << "bool type" << endl; }
```

Then `D<bool>` will still contain all the members of the class template that you haven't explicitly specialised, including the default constructor.

Comment: Beat me to it by 21 seconds (but just because I had to test this out to make sure it was possible :) ) +1

Comment: I'm aware you can specialize methods, that's why I put in the note about why I'm not doing that... My goal is to have a data member in one but not the other and not have to re-implement common methods. I understand whats happening, just don't understand why the common method can't be re-used.

Answer (score 5):

The problem is your erroneous assumption that there is anything *common* between `D<A>` and `D<B>`. Template instances are *types*, and two different instances are two different types, end of story. It only so happens that instances of the *same* template have formally similar code, but with specialization you can define any type you like. In short, every type that you define explicitly is entirely independent, and there is no commonality across specialized template instances, even if they happen to have the same name.

For example:

```
template <typename T> struct Foo
{
    T & r;
    const T t;
    void gobble(const T &);
    Foo(T *);
};

template <> struct Foo<int>
{
    std::vector<char> data;
    int gobble() const;
    Foo(bool, int, Foo<char> &);
};
```

The types `Foo<char>` and `Foo<int>` have nothing to do with one another, and there is no reason why any part of one should have any use inside the other.

If you want to factor out common features, use private inheritance:

```
template <typename> struct D : private DImpl { /* ... */ }
```

Comment: Not making any assumptions, just wondering why I can't tell the compiler to use the default implementation for the template. I understand every template type is a different type regardless of specialization, but that goes to my point. If the compiler can use the same method for both types, why not for a specialization as long as there are no conflicts

Comment: @Jaime: Well, I don't think there's an answer beyond "because that's how C++ is designed", but consider also that this isn't possible for ordinary classes, where it's really the exact same argument: Why can't one class inherit a partial implementation of another class? Well, it *can* by using inheritance :-) (As I suggest in my answer.)

Comment: I would love to see in the standard where it explicitly says this is against the "design". It seems to me that its more about how its implemented. Why is it illogical to expect the default implementation for the template be used versus the re-implementing in the specialization? I don't see it.

Answer (score 1):

You need to reimplement it because `D<T>` and `D<bool>` are totally unrelated classes (they just happen to "share the name"). That's just how templates work.

If you want the classes to share construction code, just put that code inside `B::B` (i.e. the same thing you do every time you want to reuse code in different branches of the same hierarchy: move the code up and let inheritance handle the rest).

Answer (score 0):

Consider that `D<T>::D()` will be responsible for default-constructing `string data`, and that `D<bool>` doesn't have any such member.  Clearly there is no way to use the same emitted code in each case.

However, if your default constructor doesn't do anything (in *either* version here), just omit it and allow the compiler to do the work.

Comment: Same issue with a method other than the constructor.