# C++ Templates / Specialization

Tags: c++, templates

I want to have a class that is accessible with and without template parameters. See the example below. I did some research but didn't find anything helpful, except template specialization but that is not what I want.

```
class Execute
{
  ...
}

template<class T>
class Execute
{
  ...
}
```

I want to be able to create objects of these classes like:

```
Execute exec1;
Execute<int> exec1;
```

Does anyone have an idea on how to achieve this? I did several setups but none did succeed.

Comment: What are you actually trying to do?

Comment: see also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8789867/c-template-class-specialization-why-do-common-methods-need-to-be-re-implement

Comment: Template specialization is your only option, other than default template parameters as Anton points out below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not exactly what you want, but you can specify a default template argument:

```
template<class T = void>
class Execute
{
};

template<>
class Execute<void>
{
};

Execute<> exec1; // Instantiates Execute<void>
Execute<int> exec2;
```

Comment: thanks for your comment, this could be an option! However suppose I want two different constructors one for the Execute class with type void and one with all the other types. I could do a check with the C++ 11 method is_same, but I was thinking how it's possible without C++ 11?

Comment: @CédricVerstraeten you just specialize `Execute<void>` and do whatever you want there. See my updated answer.